# Struggles solving : $\frac23xyy'=\sqrt{x^6-y^4}+y^2.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $\frac23xyy'=\sqrt{x^6-y^4}+y^2.$
> (Hint: the equation can be boiled down to a homogeneous one.)

**My attempt:**

I didn't know how to obtain a homogeneous equation, so I'm going to show what I did instead.

We can write $\frac23xyy'=|x|^3\sqrt{1-\frac{y^4}{x^6}}+y^2.$ Let $z=\frac{y^2}{x^3}=y^2x^{-3}.$ Then
$$\begin{aligned}z'&=2yy'x^{-3}-3y^2x^{-4}\\ \implies x^4z'&=2xyy'-3y^2\\ \implies\frac23xyy'&=\frac{x^4z'+3y^2}3=\frac{x^4z'}3+y^2\\ \implies\frac{x^4z'}3+y^2&=|x|^3\sqrt{1-z^2}+y^2\\ \implies\frac{|x|z'}3&=\sqrt{1-z^2}\\ \implies\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}&=3\frac{dx}{|x|}\\ \implies\arcsin z&=3\ln|x|+C, C\in\Bbb R\\ \implies z&=\sin\ln(C|x|^3), C>0\\ \implies y^2&=x^3\sin\ln(C|x|^3)C>0.\end{aligned}$$

I'm not sure my answer is correct. I didn't get far plugging the result into the equation.
How do we solve the given ODE? Or should I better ask, how do we obtain a homogeneous ODE from it?

Comment: I think you made a good substitution; in essence, you did get a homogeneous equation, which was variables separable, and you solved it. If you plug it in, and if it works, you win!

Comment: Your calculation is only valid for $x>0$. Make a separate case for $x<0$ or use $\int\frac{dx}{|x|}={\rm sign}(x)(\ln|x|+c)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can obtain the homogenious equation as follows.

$$\begin{align}
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{x}{3}\cdot \frac{d(y^2)}{dx} = \sqrt{(x^3)^2-y(^2)^2}+y^2\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x^3\cdot \frac{d(y^2)}{3x^2dx} = \sqrt{(x^3)^2-y(^2)^2}+y^2\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x^3\cdot \frac{d(y^2)}{d(x^3)} = \sqrt{(x^3)^2-y(^2)^2}+y^2\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{d(y^2)}{d(x^3)} = \frac{\sqrt{(x^3)^2-y(^2)^2}+y^2}{x^3} \tag{1}\\
\end{align}$$
Let's denote $(p,t) = (y^2,x^3)$ then
$$(1) \Longleftrightarrow  \frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt{t^2-p^2}+p}{t} \tag{2}$$

$(2)$ is homogenious and you can solve it easily (for example, transform $(2)$ to an equation of $\frac{p}{t}$).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac23xyy'=\sqrt{x^6-y^4}+y^2.$$
$$x^3(y^2)'=3x^2\sqrt{x^6-y^4}+3x^2y^2$$
$$\dfrac {x^3(y^2)'-3x^2y^2}{x^6}=\dfrac 3 {x^4}\sqrt{x^6-y^4}$$
$$\left (\dfrac {y^2}{x^3}\right)'=\dfrac 3 {x^4}\sqrt{x^6-y^4}$$
$$\left (\dfrac {y^2}{x^3}\right)'=\dfrac 3 {x}\sqrt{1-\left (\dfrac {y^2}{x^3}\right)^2}$$
The DE is separable.
Substitute $u=\left (\dfrac {y^2}{x^3}\right)$:
$$\dfrac {du}{ \sqrt{1- u^2}}=\dfrac 3x dx$$

Answer (score 0):

To make it homogeneous, we use the following variable change

$y=t^{a}$ so $~dy=at^{a-1}~dt$

$\frac{2}{3}ax t^{2a-1}~dt=(\sqrt{x^{6}-t^{4a}}+t^{2a})~dx$

To be homogeneous : $2a=3$ ,so $a=\frac{3}{2}$

$xt^{2}~dt=(\sqrt{x^{6}-t^{6}}+t^{3})~dx$ , $t=zx$

$z'x+z=\frac{\sqrt{1-z^{6}}+z^{3}}{z^{2}}$

$\int\frac{z^2}{\sqrt{1-z^{6}}}~dz=\int\frac{1}{x}~dx$

$arcsin(z^{3}) =3\ln(x)+C$

we had : $z=\frac{t}{x}$ , $t=y^{\frac{2}{3}}$

$$y^{2}=x^{3}sin(3\ln(x)+C)$$